# how to print a log for every element inserted into the HashMap?

Tags: hashmap

I need to use  an API which accepts hash `map` as an argument.

However, there was requirement to print a log whenever I insert a value for a key in the map. Values for the keys are assigned by reading from the external csv file.

For instance,

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

myMap.put("nodeId", myMap.get("nodeIDForCreationOfTrackedAsset"));
myMap.put("templateAssetID", myMap.get("assetIdForServiceHistory"));
myMap.put("seqId", "{{db.WM_TS001.SeqNum}}");
myMap.put("badgeId", "{{db.WM_TS001.BadgeNum}}");
myMap.put("serialId","{{db.WM_TS001.SerialNum}}");
```

So everytime when I use myMap.put(key,value), it should print a log to an external file, some thing like below

```
element nodeId is assigned to "value" successfully.
element seqId is assigned to  "value" successfully.
element templateAssetID is assigned to "value" successfully.
element badgeId is assigned to "value" successfully.
element serialId is assigned to "value" successfully.
```

Is there any generic way to do this, such that log can be printed through the program whenever `myMap.put(key,value)` is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to do this is to extend HashMap and then declare myMap to be an object of the new subclass.  For example:

```
public class LoggingHashMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    @Overrides
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        Log.i("LOG", "put:" + key + ":" + value;
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}

Map<String, String> myMap = new LoggingHashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: I've added more above.  The logging I've added is for Android and I don't know if that's what you're using.  If you're not, then substitue that line with your own logging statement.

Comment: Hi Nacho. Thank you very much. I haven't tried it yet. Will try it today. I was working on other task. Also curious to know if it is possible to check/make if certain keys in the Map are optional. And whenever a key is assigned to value which is successfully accepted by our webservice, then the log statement be pass and if the value for a key is not accepted, the log statement should throw error. And the requirement was to create a ouput log text file with all these log statements. So right now I am stuck there.

Comment: Hi Sriram,  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for now, but I'm sure that my original response will work for what you originally asked for.  If you need more help with the new things you need, I suggest you ask a new question.  Thanks

Comment: Sure Nacho. I will ask a new question. Thanks again so much.